# Error while generating Slack oauth token due to scope

Tags: scope, oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api

While generating a token to use the Slack APIs, I have given the following scopes:

> channels:history channels:read channels:write chat:write:user dnd:read dnd:write emoji:read files:read files:write:user
>   groups:history groups:read groups:write im:history im:read im:write
>   links:read links:write mpim:history mpim:read mpim:write pins:read
>   pins:write reactions:read reactions:write reminders:read
>   reminders:write search:read stars:read stars:write team:read
>   usergroups:read usergroups:write users.profile:read
>   users.profile:write users:read users:read.email users:write post bot
>   chat:write:bot

However, when I hit the authorize URL: I get an error

> Invalid permissions requested Cannot request object scopes with
>   deprecated scopes

I need the bot scope scope as well as post scope for Conversations APIs.
What is wrong in the scopes that I mentioned? Is there any invalid combination?

Answer (score 3):

Yes `bot` and `post` is an invalid combination, it’s documented here: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes

But `post` is deprecated you should not need it if you are already requesting `channels:write`, `group:write`, `mpim:write` and `im:write`.